# ASP.NET Core Rendering SDK , Every time i have to run docker-compose restart rendering cm to reflect the changes

Tags: rendering-host

I am doing some R&D in **ASP.NET Core Rendering SDK**, Whenever I make the changes in `.cshtml` file, I need to run this command `docker-compose restart rendering cm` to reflect the changes. Is this the right way to see the changes?

As per my understanding, this is a connected mode so we don't have to do anything. changes will automatically trigger and push to the CM environment.

I am using the default template project of

```
dotnet new sitecore.aspnet.gettingstarted -n MyProject
```

Here is the logs

```
watch : Killing process 1612
watch : Process id 1612 ran for 121995ms
watch : Exited
watch : File changed: C:\solution\src\rendering\Views\Shared\Components\SitecoreComponent\Demo.cshtml
watch : Modifying command to use --no-restore
watch : Started 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' 'run --no-restore --no-launch-profile' with process id 2988
watch : Running dotnet with the following arguments: run --no-restore --no-launch-profile
watch : Started
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Sdk.Razor.CurrentVersion.targets(750,5): 
warning MSB3026: Could not copy "C:\solution\src\rendering/obj/container/Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProject.Views.dll" to "C:\solution\src\rendering\bin\container\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProject.Views.dll". 
Beginning retry 5 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 
'C:\solution\src\rendering\bin\container\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProject.Views.dll' because it is being used by another process. [C:\solution\src\rendering\RenderingHost.csproj]
watch : Waiting for a file to change before restarting dotnet...
The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
watch : Exited with error code 1
```

Comment: Can you share the logs from your `rendering` container? Any errors? You should see it recompiling there on any changes.

Comment: @nickwesselman: I have updated the question and provided the logs of the rendering project.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in a recent update to Docker Desktop or Windows. I'm able to [reproduce the issue](https://github.com/nickwesselman/dotnet-docker-lock-issue) in a simple Dockerized ASP.NET Core application. It appears others may be witnessing [similar behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752750/visual-studio-build-fails-while-copying-files-to-the-bin-directory-due-to-file-l).

I've [reported the issue to Docker moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42803). In the meantime you can change your `rendering` container to use a `dotnet run` instead, though that will still require a `build` and `up` with each change. You can also use `dotnet watch` outside of Docker, for example:

```
dotnet watch --project .\src\rendering\ run
```

Comment: Has this issue been solved yet?