# Sitecore Helix .Net Core example publishing/build errors

Tags: helix, docker

When making any edits to the cshtml files. I get a `bad gateway` error on CD and on CM I get a `The operation has timed out error`. So far the only way to get the sites working again, is doing a `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up -d`. Then the site responds correctly and also shows the change I made too.

[image: operation has timed out.]

[image: badgateway]

Comment: I have also tried to downgrade to docker 4.6.1 and rebuild my images and the same thing happens.. I have tried 3 different docker examples and the same issue happens... When I look at the rendering logs this is the error I get...  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.420\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4651,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "C:\solution\src\Feature\Navigation\rendering\obj\container\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\BasicCompany.Feature.Navigation.Views.dll"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29566/asp-net-core-rendering-sdk-every-time-i-have-to-run-docker-compose-restart-ren), it's a bug in Docker Desktop for Windows. Running `docker-compose restart rendering cm` before you refresh the page will allow it to load properly. I know this doesn't exactly "fix" the issue, but it seems to work.

Comment: running that command does bring it up much faster.. so at least its something to work with thanks.. hopefully this bug gets fixed sometime soon.